# Disable responsiveness when zoomed

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently working on a responsive website, but I'd like to disable the "responsiveness" when the user zooms in or out.

I don't want to disable the ability to zoom, but rather maintain the layout of the site as it would look for that device at 100% zoom.

For example, if I'm on a desktop computer and zoom in on the page to 200%, the size will rescale to the mobile layout of the site. I really only want to zoom, without any changes.

How can I do this? All I can find on the web is how to disable zoom alltogether, and that's not what I want.

Currently all my responsive styling are in the format of:

```
@media (max-width: ____px) {
   ...
}
```

and my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are not just using this metatag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using max-width in the media query, you can use max-device-width:

```
@media (max-device-width: ____px) {
   ...
}
```

The query will then not be triggered when you resize or zoom on a screen that is wider than ____px

Comment: It solves the zooming, but the problem here is that the user would be forced to have the site full-screen or else the layout would break.

Comment: Solve that by setting a fixed width on the body. As you set the viewport width to 640, you can set a width on the body style of 640px as well. This will prevent it from shrinking